# How to de-serialize JSON data of check box values?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have multiple check box values in a form. I am serializing the form and send to mvc controller as JSON data. How can i de-serialize the check box values?

This is my html -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveOfficeConfiguration", "Offices", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "frmOfficeConfigSave" }))
{  
<div id="divOfficeForm">
    <div style="width: auto; height: auto; border: 3px outset silver;">
        <table class="mainsectionable" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">
                        <center>KCCM Profile Access</center>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm())
                        {
                            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Brands = ViewBag.GetBrands;
                            foreach (var item in Brands)
                            {
                            @Html.CheckBox("KCCM_Brands", false, new
                                                        {
                                                            value = item.Value
                                                        });
                            <label>@item.Text</label><br />
                                            }
                                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

This is my javascript function-

```
function SaveOfficeConfigNew() {
    var officeID = $('input[name="hdnOfficeID"]').val();
    var url = "/OfficeManagement/Offices/SaveOfficeConfiguration?officeID=" + officeID;
    ShowWait();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: frmOfficeConfigSave.$('input').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            HideWait();
            alert(data.msg);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            HideWait();
            alert(data.msg);
        }
    });
    applyFilter();
    return false;
}
```

This is my gonna be controller action -

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveOfficeConfiguration(int ? officeID, FormCollection form)
    {
        try
        {
            */..............
              ..............*/
            return Json(new
            {
                success = true,
                msg = String.Empty,
                id = 1

            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                success = false,
                msg = error.Message,
                id = -1
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to receive a `List<string>` parameter, with the same name you're giving the checkboxes, i.e., `KCM_Brands`. The Model Binder will deserialize it directly for you.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveOfficeConfiguration(int ? officeID, FormCollection form,
  List<string> KCM_Brands)
{
    ....
}
```

To serialize your form data to post it, use the function suggedted in this post:

[JSON object post using form serialize not mapping to c# object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756844/json-object-post-using-form-serialize-not-mapping-to-c-sharp-object)

Comment: Its `null`, any issues in my javascript function?

Comment: I didn't check your js. And yes, it's wrong. I thoght you had checked what was being sent with the alerts. Look ad the reference I've added

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FormsCollection` to retrieve the check box values:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveOfficeConfiguration(int ? officeID, FormCollection form) 
{
var CheckBoxValues = form["KCCM_Brands"].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=>int.Parse(x));
}
```

For More info Have a look here :
http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/2ee905ba-aea1-4d83-a49d-d8d8fb10c747/?Checkbox%20control%20in%20MVC

Comment: I have 3 check boxes, I checked first and last and then submitted the form. I controller when I used your code, I got the values as `"1","false","false","3","false"`

Comment: you will have to remove those false from your list.
your results is giving you the selected checboxes.

Comment: How do I know the selected check boxes from this values?

Comment: Im confused here, I couldnt found any value here.

Comment: @sandy visit the link in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@Html.CheckBox("KCCM_Brands", false, new
{
    value = item.Value
});
```

use this code to generate checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="KCCM_Brands" value="@item.Value" />
```

The action on your controller should look like this

```
public ActionResult SaveOfficeConfiguration(int? officeID, List<string> KCCM_Brands)
```

When you post your form, `List<string> KCCM_Brands` will be populated only with the values of selected checkboxes.

Also, I don't know if your javascript is correct, but I had to make the following change for it to work

```
data: $('#frmOfficeConfigSave input').serialize()
```

Comment: I have to follow Json serialization

Comment: `List<string> KCCM_Brands` is `null`!